# React native asyncstorage not working properly

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 navigators in my react native app .

I'm trying to conditionally use them in the App.js

I set item in one of my screens and then I'm trying to do this

```
  export default function App() {
  const logedStatus = AsyncStorage.getItem('logedIn').then(logedIn => logedIn)
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {logedStatus.length === 0 ? <Navigator /> : <LogedInNav/>}
      <Snackbar />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

No matter how many times I try to start app it always renders the  logedInNav navigation, I'm confused, does store never get empty if u don't clear it by yourself? or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use state  and useEffect

```
 import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
 export default function App() {
   const[logedStatus,setlogedStatus])useState(false)
  useEffect(()=>{
     let mounted=true;
      AsyncStorage.getItem('logedIn').then(logedIn =>{
             if(mounted) setlogedStatus(logedIn)
       })
      return()=>{mounted=false;}
  },[])

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {logedStatus.length === 0 ? <Navigator /> : <LogedInNav/>}
      <Snackbar />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you please explain why do you return mounted in the end?

Comment: yeah ofcourse. what I did is called ```useEffect``` cleanup . the returned function in ```useEffect``` is called on component unmount , so I am making sure that I'm only updating the state when the component is mounted because otherwise the app will crash as you can't update state of un unmounted component , because you component may unmount before ``` AsyncStorage.getItem('logedIn')```  resolves .